# Status read failed Too many links on Ream me 8 pro root device

Tags: android, root, su

I am not able to root my realme 8 pro device, i just follow bellowed command,

```
> unlocked developer option.
> turn on OEM unlocking and USB debugging
> Download and install Magisk
```

Then i am not able to find **boot.img** for my device, so i have to unlock my device using adb command.

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

using this command i am able to load device into fastboot mode then checking device is connected or not i run this command `fastboot devices` it will show my device id with some random alphabets

```
fastboot flashing unlock
```

For unlock device i try above command but it will get error like :

```
FAILED (Status read failed (Too many links)) i am also try `fastboot oem unlock` but not working.
```